# Does single or double quote matter in str_ireplace in PHP?

Tags: php, replace

I've to replace newline (\n) with & in a string so that the received data could be parsed with parse_str() into array. The thing is that when I put \n in single quote it somehow turns out as to be replaced with a space:

```
str_ireplace(array('&', '+', '\n'), array('', '', '&'), $response)
"id=1 name=name gender=gender age=age friends=friends"
```

But when I put \n in double quotes then it works just fine:

```
str_ireplace(array('&', '+', "\n"), array('', '', '&'), $response)
"id=1&name=name&gender=gender&age=age&friends=friends"
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because only the escaped sequences `\'` and `\\`  have a meaning in single quoted strings.
 See the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (`\`). To specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`). All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as `\r` or `\n`, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

**Update:**

Another difference is that PHP only [substitutes variables inside double-quoted strings (and heredoc)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). Therefore you can consider processing of single-quoted strings to be faster in general (but maybe not measurably faster).

---

Btw you don't necessarily need to use `str_ireplace` as `&`, `+` and `\n` have no upper or lower case version. There is just one version, so `str_replace` would be enough.

Comment: Yep, I write my code in single quotes as its faster in general. Thanks for both tips - changed to str_replace! :}